# JQuery Validate Plugin - How to verify if all fields of a Form are numeric

Tags: jquery, methods, validation

I have a form with 10 fields to be verified as numeric, I would like to validate all the fields as numeric but I don't want to do something like: `#field:{number:true}` to all the fields.

Adding a "Custom Method" or addClassRules would be the fast solution.

How could I create a "Custom Method" to verify a certain Class like `.number` to "replace" the current way to validate as `#id:{ required:true, number:true}`?

I found the answer and I hope it'll be helpful.

`$(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery.validator.addClassRules({

       fieldNumber: { required: true, number: true

    }

   });

});`

This function validates any field with class="fieldNumber"

Let me know If this function helped adding a comment.

Thank you all

Comment: Can you post your solution ? I am trying to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $(':text').each(function(){
            // put other rules here
            if(isNaN($(this).val()))
            {
               $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/Q9HhG/)**

Comment: Thank you!

I was able to create my custom function on the Jquery Validate plugin after read more the documentation and use addClassRules.